# jQuery click bind for dynamically created buttons: whole div reacts to a click

Tags: jquery, bind

### I create a DIV dynamically:

```
        shareVisual = '<div class="individual-share">' + '<input type="number" value="1" /> X ' + classname.val() + '@' + classcurrency.val() + ' ' + classprice.val() + ' per share ' + '<button type="button" class="remove-share">Remove</button></div>';
        listOfSharesBox.append(shareVisual);
```

---

Then add a bind to the parent div:

```
$("#list-of-shares").bind('click', '.remove-share', function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest("div").remove();
})
```

Problem: the div gets removed when any part of the dynamically generated DIV is clicked. I need this to work only when button is clicked. What do i need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), not `bind`, to delegate with a selector :

```
$("#list-of-shares").on('click', '.remove-share', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list-of-shares").on('click', '.remove-share', function(e) {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
})
```